# Configuring proxy for JAX-RS 2.0 client API

Tags: jax-rs, java-ee-7

I have an application that is running on a Java EE 7 application server (WildFly), that queries another service using REST resources.

In previous applications I have used the Jersey 1.x client API. Access to the REST service is granted through a web proxy.

In Jersey I create the `Client` instance like this:

```java
public Client create() {

    Client client;
    if ( proxyConfiguration != null && proxyConfiguration.getHost() != null && !proxyConfiguration.getHost().trim().isEmpty() ) {
        HttpURLConnectionFactory urlConnectionFactory = new ProxyUrlConnectionFactory( proxyConfiguration );
        client = new Client( new URLConnectionClientHandler( urlConnectionFactory ), clientConfig );
    } else {
        client = Client.create( clientConfig );
    }

    return client;
}
```

Running on a Java EE 7 application server I wanted to use the JAX-RS 2.0 client API which is provided by the application server.

Now I am having a really hard time to find information on how to configure the JAX-RS 2.0 client in a platform independent way. Setting the `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort` system properties had no effect in WildFly (I would prefer to not configure it globally anyway).

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think there's no vendor independent solution (at least, I didn't find anything related to proxies in the JAX-RS API).

For Jersey 2.x, you can try:

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
config.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_URI, "192.168.1.254:8080");  
Client client = ClientBuilder.withConfig(config).build();
```

[`ClientProperties`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.9/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/ClientProperties.html) is a class from Jersey API.

---

For RESTEasy, the configuration is:

```
Client client = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
                   .defaultProxy("192.168.1.254", 8080, "http")
                   .build();
```

[`ResteasyClientBuilder`](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.13.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/ResteasyClientBuilder.html) is a class from RESTEasy API.

Comment: thank you very much. I feared that much - I guess I could specify Resteasy as provided dependency. I hoped to avoid vendor-lockin

Comment: @MaxFichtelmann Actually, I'm not happy with this solution. The [JAX-RS 2.0 JSR](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf) mentions the word *proxy* only once and, unfortunately, it's not related to *network proxies*. IMHO, that's the kind of thing that could be covered by the next version of the specification.

Answer (score 0):

With (WildFly and) RESTEasy (6.2.1.Final) set a proxy with:

```java
final Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
    .property("org.jboss.resteasy.jaxrs.client.proxy.host", "192.168.1.254")
    .property("org.jboss.resteasy.jaxrs.client.proxy.port", 8080)
.build();
```

See [Jakarta RESTFul Web Services: 51.3.3. HTTP proxy](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/6.2.1.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#http_proxy).