# proxy for the REST

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I have a method in which sending XML(byte array) through REST. I set the global properties of a test proxy (CCProxy). In the application CCProxy log I have nothing. What did I do wrong?

```
url = "https://myurl/api/Storage/Init";
SSLContext sc = createSslContext();
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sc).hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
    public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
        return true;
    }
}).build();
System.setProperty("http.proxySet", "true");
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "192.168.11.64");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "808");
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "192.168.11.64");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "808");
// client.property("http.proxy.server.uri", "192.168.11.64");
// client.property("http.proxy.server.port", "808");
// client.property("https.proxy.server.uri", "192.168.11.64");
// client.property("https.proxy.server.port", "808");
javax.ws.rs.core.Response response = client.target(url).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .post(Entity.entity(doc, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
```

*setting CCProxy*

[image: setting CCProxy]

The second question, how to set the proxy only for a particular method? I tried something like this but it did not work.

```
client.property("http.proxy.server.uri", "192.168.11.64");
client.property("http.proxy.server.port", "808");
```

**Update: After the changes as suggested by CWasp**

```
final SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
    .loadTrustMaterial(null, (x509CertChain, authType) -> true).build();

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
    .setProxy(new HttpHost("192.168.11.64", 808))
    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credProvider).setProxyAuthenticationStrategy(new ProxyAuthenticationStrategy())
    .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
    .setSSLContext(sslContext)
    .build();

ApacheHttpClient4Engine engine = new ApacheHttpClient4Engine(httpClient);
client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().httpEngine(engine).build();
```

Comment: You can try solution from hire http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872492/configure-proxy-for-jaxrs-2-client

Comment: Ok works. But what if the proxy requires a username and password?

Answer (score 4):

Try this if proxy authentication required

For Jersey 2.x:

```
    ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    config.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());
    config.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_URI, "http://" + PROXY_HOST + ":" + PROXY_PORT);
    config.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_USERNAME, PROXY_USER);
    config.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_PASSWORD, PROXY_PASS);
    JerseyClient client = new JerseyClientBuilder()
            .withConfig(config)
            .build();
```

For Resteasy:

```
    Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASS);
    CredentialsProvider credProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT), credentials);
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .setProxy(new HttpHost(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT))
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credProvider)
            .setProxyAuthenticationStrategy(new ProxyAuthenticationStrategy())
            .build();
    ApacheHttpClient4Engine engine = new ApacheHttpClient4Engine(httpClient);
    ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder()
            .httpEngine(engine)
            .build();
```

Comment: I added 

.setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
.setSslcontext(new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, x509Certificates, s) -> true).build())

because I had a mistake. Unfortunately logs have information that an unknown user.

Comment: Where do your add setSSLHostnameVerifier? For Resteasy it must be added to HttpClientBuilder because with custom engine resteasy ignore connection settings from ResteasyClientBuilder

Comment: Which logs have information about unknown user? Proxy server or rest service?

Comment: CCProxy server.

Comment: I install CCProxy. All works fine with authentication. Can you submit log?